# How do I upgrade this type definition to Julia 1.x via 0.7.0?

Tags: julia

I'm new to Julia and I am trying to upgrade the package [BayesianDataFusion.jl](https://github.com/suchow/BayesianDataFusion.jl) from Julia 0.4.7 to 1.x via 0.7.0. The package defines a new type `Entity` as follows:

```
@compat type Entity{FT,R}
  F::FT
  FF
  use_FF::Bool
  Frefs::Vector{Future}
  relations::Vector{R}
  count::Int64
  name::AbstractString

  modes::Vector{Int}
  modes_other::Vector{Vector{Int}}

  lambda_beta::Float64
  lambda_beta_sample::Bool
  mu::Float64   ## Hyper-prior for lambda_beta
  nu::Float64   ## Hyper-prior for lambda_beta

  model::EntityModel
  @compat Entity(F, relations::Vector{R}, count::Int64, name::AbstractString, lb::Float64=1.0, lb_sample::Bool=true, mu=1.0, nu=1e-3) = new(F, zeros(0,0), false, Future[], relations, count, name, Int[], Vector{Int}[], lb, lb_sample, mu, nu)
end

Entity(name::AbstractString; F=zeros(0,0), lambda_beta=1.0) = Entity{Any,Relation}(F::Any, Relation[], 0, name, lambda_beta)
```

I began by making the obvious changes, including removing the two `@compat`s and changing `type` to `mutable struct`. Next, I was notified that there were `too few type parameters specified in "new{...}"` and so I added `FT` and `R` as type parameters to the `new()` call and `where {FT,R}` to the left-hand side of the assignment on the line before `end`.

The type definition now looks like this:

```
mutable struct Entity{FT,R}
  F::FT
  FF
  use_FF::Bool
  Frefs::Vector{Future}
  relations::Vector{R}
  count::Int64
  name::AbstractString

  modes::Vector{Int}
  modes_other::Vector{Vector{Int}}

  lambda_beta::Float64
  lambda_beta_sample::Bool
  mu::Float64   ## Hyper-prior for lambda_beta
  nu::Float64   ## Hyper-prior for lambda_beta

  model::EntityModel
  Entity(F, relations::Vector{R}, count::Int64, name::AbstractString, lb::Float64=1.0, lb_sample::Bool=true, mu=1.0, nu=1e-3) where {FT,R} = new{FT,R}(F, zeros(0,0), false, Future[], relations, count, name, Int[], Vector{Int}[], lb, lb_sample, mu, nu)
end

Entity(name::AbstractString; F=zeros(0,0), lambda_beta=1.0) = Entity{Any,Relation}(F::Any, Relation[], 0, name, lambda_beta)
```

However, I am now seeing an error I do not understand:

```
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching Entity{Any,Relation}(::Array{Float64,2}, ::Array{Relation,1}, ::Int64, ::String, ::Float64)
```

I reread the Julia documentation on types, and based on my understanding, there *is* a method matching the given signature.

Isn't that exactly what the code on the last line defines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling inner constructor, not struct constructor, and inner constructor do not have a parametric definition, so you just need to remove it

```
Entity(name::AbstractString; F=zeros(0,0), lambda_beta=1.0) = Entity(F, Relation[], 0, name, lambda_beta)
```

Also, may be it's a typo, but you've missed type annotation in inner constructor, it should be  (notice `F::FT`)

```
Entity(F::FT, relations::Vector{R}, count::Int64, name::AbstractString, lb::Float64=1.0, lb_sample::Bool=true, mu=1.0, nu=1e-3) where {FT,R} = new{FT,R}(F, zeros(0,0), false, Future[], relations, count, name, Int[], Vector{Int}[], lb, lb_sample, mu, nu)
```